# Trying to install via USB: ACPI Bios Error (bug) AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: boot, acpi, usb-installation

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu after had lots of problems trying to make TensorFlow GPU runs.

I used Rufus with Ubuntu 22.04, and when I tried to boot I got this:

[image]

I was not able to pass this message only restart or shutdown

How can I fix this?

Comment: can we get some hardware info? what kind of computer is this? You migth consider updating your bios.

Answer (score -1):

The "solution" was migrate to Ubuntu 23 again, because this version is able to  continue after this error