# ACPI Error : AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, Failure creating named object while trying to install Ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, bios, acpi

ASUS Strix G16, SSD, NVIDIA 4060 GPU, 19 13980HX CPU, Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.3.

[image]

Comment: These are notifications of difference between what BIOS tells the kernel and the kernel expects to receive. We users can't fix those, only supporess. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7 or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493148/trying-to-install-via-usb-acpi-bios-error-bug-ae-already-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7)